# Why it is faster writing a file which is freopened with stdout?

Tags: c++, performance, stdout, freopen

When executed on Windows, this test code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    // The clock() function returns an approximation of processor time used by the program.
    // The  value  returned is the CPU time used so far as a clock_t;
    // to get the number of seconds used, divide by CLOCKS_PER_SEC.
    auto buf = new char[1048576]; // 1MB
    auto cache = new char[512 * 1024];

    // initialize the buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < 1048576; ++i)
        buf[i] = i;

    auto fp_reopen = freopen("data_freopen.bin", "wb", stdout);
    assert(fp_reopen != nullptr);
    setvbuf(fp_reopen, cache, _IOLBF, 512 * 1024);
    auto clock_begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        auto n = fwrite(buf, 1048576, 1, fp_reopen);
        assert(n == 1);
    }
    fflush(fp_reopen);
    auto clock_end = clock();

#ifdef _WIN32
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
#else
    freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);
#endif

    printf("write with freopen clocks elapsed: %zu\n", clock_end - clock_begin);

    auto fp = fopen("data_fopen.bin", "wb");
    assert(fp != nullptr);
    setvbuf(fp, cache, _IOLBF, 512 * 1024);
    clock_begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        auto n = fwrite(buf, 1048576, 1, fp);
        assert(n == 1);
    }
    fflush(fp);
    clock_end = clock();
    fclose(fp);

    printf("write with fopen clocks elapsed: %zu\n", clock_end - clock_begin);
    delete[] buf;
    delete[] cache;
    getchar();
}
```

Generates these results:

- `write with freopen clocks elapsed: 2767`
- `write with fopen clocks elapsed: 8337`

Why?

Comment: Please include your code as part of your question instead of hosting it offsite. We shouldn't have to leave Stack Overflow to understand it.

Comment: Just swap the two test and try again.

Comment: @Chris Sorry about this. I edited the question on mobile phone. Thanks for your reminder and help!

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is interesting, but highly system specific:

- on Linux with gcc and the Glibc, I get very similar timings for both runs
- on OS/X, with clang and the Apple Libc, the `fopen` timings seem consistently a little faster than the `freopen` ones.
- you are running your test on Windows, as the final call to `getchar()` suggests... I unfortunately cannot test this system to try and cross check your observations.

It is possible that Microsoft did something weird in their runtime library, but more likely you are really benchmarking the creation of 2 separate 1GB files. It is possible that the second file takes longer to create than the first one, due to the state of your file system, its cache or other OS specific causes. You should try and remove this potential side effect by removing each file after closing it, or try running the tests in a different order.

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I change the tests' order, the result reverses.
* `write with fopen clocks elapsed: 2346`
* `write with freopen clocks elapsed: 8088`